# Parquet Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet, bigdata

I am trying to read parquet file using Spark. Spark version is 1.3.0.
When I try to read I get below exception. Any help is highly appreciated.
CDH version : 5.4.3

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:249)
>           at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:543)
>           at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:520)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:426)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:381)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:155)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:138)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:153)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:124)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Any Updates  on the above question?

Comment: Please refer to this Jira issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11558